# Prompt the way to edit csv

Tags: csv, awk

I have an csv file like:

```
1;2,3,4
5;2,3
etc
```

I need to get file like:

```
1;12
1;13
1;14
5;52
5;53
```

Can i do that without deep programming, maybe something like awk or something. I can do this thing on perl or python, but ш think there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{n=split($2, a, ","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, $1a[i]}' file
1;12
1;13
1;14
5;52
5;53
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` set input and output field separator as `;`.
- `{n=split($2, a, ",")` slice the second field based on comma. The pieces are stored in the array `a[]`.
- `for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, $1a[i]}` loop through the fields in `a[]` printing them together with the first field on the format FIRST_FIELD;FIRST_FIELD + a[i]

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '[;,]' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) print $1 ";" $1 $i }' file
```

Output:

```
1;12
1;13
1;14
5;52
5;53
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[;,]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s;%s%s\n",$1,$1,$i}' a.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `-F';|,'` Split line by `,` or `;`
- `{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s;%s%s\n",$1,$1,$i}` Iterate though columns and produce output as desired.

Comment: @fedorqui Oh. missed that. Updated the answer. Thanks for your advice! :)

Comment: This wont work, it will print $1 as the second part on the first output field and will also miss off the last field on each line.

Comment: Uhms, note also you need to use `NF` and not `$NF`: you need the number of fields, not the value of the last one.

Comment: You need to start the loop at 2, not at 1. Also, when using a list of characters in an RE (or FS), IMHO it's clearest to specify them using the character list construct instead of an or-separate set of RE segments, i.e. use `'[;,]'` instead of `';|,'`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the hint. Basic problem was, that I had no time to fix problems. Let me do this now. Yes, `[;,]` looks better than `;|,`.. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
awk -F";" '{sub(/;/,FS $1);gsub(/,/,ORS $1";"$1)}7' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo "1;2,3,4
5;2,3"|awk -F";" '{sub(/;/,FS $1);gsub(/,/,ORS $1";"$1)}7' 
1;12
1;13
1;14
5;52
5;53
```

or:

```
awk -F";" 'sub(/;/,FS $1)+gsub(/,/,ORS $1";"$1)' file
```